# View all disabled or hidden linux kernel options

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel

I am trying to build a 3.12 Linux Kernel and I see some of the options (sub menus) are hidden and their branch (menu entry) is disabled in `make menuconfig`. [`----` instead of being  `--->`]

I know it is because of my system profile or their dependencies but I want to view all of them.

What helped in the previous kernels was a key-shortcut, (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in file manager) that shows every option and menu. What is that shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the Wikipedia page for [menuconfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menuconfig) I do not see a similar option. There's a bullet within that page that states the following:

> The help information is distributed throughout the kernel source tree in the various files called Kconfig.

So one could use `grep` to search for whatever you wanted through these files. You can also use <kbd>?</kbd> within `menuconfig` to summon the help on a given topic too. The key your lookinig for to show hidden menus and submenus appears to be <kbd>z</kbd>.

There's also this keyboard shortcut table included in the topic:

[image: ss #1]

#### References

- [README.Menuconfig](http://www.cs.albany.edu/~sdc/Linux/linux/scripts/README.Menuconfig)